# Live search project

Tags: php, json, ajax

I have a live search project and I don't know if it's secure enough or not. I don't access it directly, but I get data by JSON so I shouldn't worry about slashes or quotes, right?

The PHP code:

```
<?php
if (isset($it_server)) {
    class search{
        public function gettingvalues($search_value){
            require_once('db_conx.php');
            $dir = "usersimage/";
            $search_value = htmlspecialchars($search_value,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
            $sql = "SELECT name,img,username FROM users WHERE username like '$search_value%' || name like '$search_value%'";
            $query = mysqli_query($conx,$sql);
            if ($query) {
                if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                        $img = $row['img'];
                        $name = $row['name'];
                        $username = $row['username'];
                        $json = array('img' => $img, 'name' => $name, 'username' => $username);
                        $results[] = $json;
                    }
                    echo json_encode($results);
                }else{
                    $json['name'] = '';
                    $json['img'] = '';
                    $json['username'] = '';
                    $json['error'] = 'No results.';
                    $results[] = $json;
                    echo json_encode($results);
                }
            }else{
                $json['name'] = '';
                $json['img'] = '';
                $json['username'] = '';
                $json['error'] = "There's a problem, please try later!";
                $results[] = $json;
                echo json_encode($results);
            }
        }
    }
}else{
    header('location: 404');
    die();
}
?>
```

I call the function from index.php:

```
<?php
    $its_server = 'yes';
    if (isset($_POST['data'])) {
        require('search.php');
        $search = new search;
        $search->gettingvalues($_POST['data']);
        header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
        die();
    }
?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input').keyup(function(){
            var value= $('input').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "",
                data: {data: value},
                datatype: "json",
                success: function(json_data) {
                    var img = [];
                    var username = [];
                    var name = [];
                    var html = '';
                    $.each(json_data, function(index, e) {
                        if (e.error) {
                            html += `${e.error}`;
                        }else{
                            html += `${e.name} ${e.username} ${e.img}<br>`;
                        }
                    })
                    $("#feedback").html(html);
                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="looking for?">
<div id="feedback"></div>
```

I don't know if I'm doing well with security or not and it's a big deal to me. So what you see from 1-10, how secure is my page?

Comment: It makes me wonder where did you get the idea that JSON is *any* related to SQL. This statement is like "I washed my hands, so I can go cross a road anywhere, no car will hit me because I am protected from germs".

Comment: Getting data by json, through jqeury, still exposes your 'live search' to the outside world, with all the security implications of that.

Answer (score 1):

One quite big security issue I see here is your vulnerability to SQL-Injection attacks. Even when you use `htmlspecialchars()`, there are still some ways to circumvent it, as shown in [*Is `htmlspecialchars` enough to prevent an SQL injection on a variable enclosed in single quotes?*](//stackoverflow.com/a/22117157).

Basically, you are allowing the user to directly manipulate the SQL-Query, which has to be prevented. For this case, there are **Prepared Statements**, which - if used correctly - will prevent the user from doing anything nasty with your database. There is [an answer to *How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?*](//stackoverflow.com/a/60496) regarding this topic, so I suggest you read and understand that.

Also, you might have a look at the manual to learn more about prepared statements using either [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

Comment: To me, this is more a comment than answer, boils down to a single SO link. And a confused one. What does it mean, "Nothing is 100% secure"? Got any evidence of gain access to a database if secured correctly?

Comment: @YourCommonSense The "Not 100%" part is more something obligatory to me, as you can't guarantee 100%, but as far as i know there is no way to bypass the current "correct" way :)

I also wasn't sure whether this counts as a full answer, but it seemed to be too much for a comment to me.

Comment: I think that Prepared Statements won't do anything for me, because index.php transfer json type data

(utf-8). What do you think?

Comment: I think that *"Use prepared statements where you can,"* is a good code review observation and worthy of an answer.  It would be better to *show* what you'd do, as well as linking to those good resources.

Comment: @TobySpeight send me an example of a good 'Prepared Statements'

Comment: @AhmadSalameh you are supposed to read the links provided in the answer. "Do i need to use prepared statements" is not a question for a code review. It is not about making your code better but about you understanding very basic principles. Which you are supposed to learn for answers on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @YourCommonSense ok i will read about it.

Comment: Is this your final answer ? I don’t want type out a lot if your going to update this ?